# Python read() not working

Tags: python-2.7, pycharm

I'm trying to open a file, read the content, compare that with a hash and if necessary overwrite the file again. Should be basic stuff, but somehow I can't get it to work. I have now:

```
with open(name, 'wb+') as des:
    current_content = des.read()
```

I'm 100% sure the file is not empty, that I'm looking at the right file (later data gets written to it and that works) but somehow current_content ends up as an empty string.

```
with open(name, 'wb+') as des:
    des.write('Test')
    des.seek(0)
    current_content = des.read()
```

If I try the above current_content will return 'Test'. Anyone an idea what could cause this behaviour?

Comment: w+ truncates the file according to open() docs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change the file reading option `wb+` to `ab+` and test it now. The problem is `ab+` supports reading and appending the data(At EOF) in a binary file according to documentation. When you are using `wb+` it may overwrite the existing file.

Comment: I'm confused now because I thought the only difference between ab+ and wb+ is the location of the pointer, beginning or EOF. Switching to ab+ didn't work, but switching to ab+ AND putting seek(0) before I read fixed it.
So if I understand right wb overwrites the file immediately when it is opened?

Comment: I'm searching the same idea, that `wb+` overwrites the file while opening. But it fells that the overwriting is implied in the documentation. `read` function starts to read the file from the end, if I remember it correctly. So seek goes to the beginning of the file.